# How to solve break error in c++ for creating 2 dimension matrix

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to create a matrix with a dimension of 200*200 in c++ using Microsoft visual studio, and I got the break errors. but the code works when the dimension is less than 100*100

The message that I got for the break is:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x7539DDC2 in NAPL-Calculation.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x007BE934.

is there any idea to solve this problem?

```
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    n=200;
    m=200;
    A=new double*[n*m];  
    for(i=0;i<n*m;i++)
        A[i]=new double[n*m];


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n`, `m` are not initialized. You also attempt to set each element to an array of the entire size. That's certainly not your intent.

Comment: I define the n and m later. it works for example for n=5 and m=10, but it does not work for n=200 and m=200

Comment: You cannot do that (defining `n` and `m` afterwords), as they will not have the intended value when the execution reaches the `new` keyword.

Comment: yes but why it is not working for for example n=200 and m=200

Comment: do you have any idea to define the matrix in another way to solve this problem?

Comment: You try to create 200*200 = 40000 entries of 200*200 = 40000  `double` variables **each**. That makes a total of 1600000000 variables. Assuming a `double` has 8 bytes,that would allocate 12800000000 bytes (i.e. 12 GB). Thats very likely not what you want and you probably don't have that much virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

What values are you trying to store in your matrix?

I would go about:

```
int m = 200, n = 200;
int A[n][m] = {0};

for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        A[j][i] = .....
    };
};
```

Comment: the value is for example 10.

Comment: 10 at all places? Then I would just replace .... by 10. Also, your line A[i] = ...           creates a 1D array. For 2D array, you'll need to use 2 loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should be like this:

```
int m = 200, n = 200;
int **A;

A = new int*[m];
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
    A[i] = new int[n];
}

...

for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    delete [] A[i];
delete [] A;
```